# comentar y descomentar codigo dinamicamente al ejecutar

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

buenas tengo un  aplicacion de consola en net4.x que ejecutan los usuarios en ambiente productivo que tiene una validacion de limites.Cuando supera esos limites el usuario no puede correr la aplicacion por tema de segurdad y cuestion de procesador .

entonces en el codigo comento la parte de esta validacion y  ejecuto la aplicacion para que pueda correr correctamente.

como podria hacer en el codigo para hacer dinamico , para no estar  comentando y descomentando esa validacion?. El codigo que comento es el siguiente:

```
 ExcedeUmbralClientes = (totalClientes > GetUmbralClientesImportar());
if (ExcedeUmbralClientes)
            {
              // hago una logica de log 
              
               return;
              //corto el proceso con return
             }
```

Se puede usar un tag #debug o algo similar ,el tema que trabajo siempre sobre produccion.
Gracias.

Comment: Puedes revisar la compilación condicional https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation

Comment: Y no deberias tener un proceso padre a quien le pidas el limite, y entonces, con un simple if, evitar que se corra eso???? no se puede comentar y descomentar codigo, este es un lenguaje compilado...

Comment: gracias por contestar , @gbianchi y como seria otra aplicacion que corra decis ?, porque tengo que quitar la validacion cuadno ejecuto yo,  capaz seria anulando la valiacion por algun flag en algun lado. por base u otro proceso.

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo.. pero no es comentar y descomentar, es un simple if con una validacion de control.. no se porque pensaste algo tan complicado...

Comment: Si es una app de consola puedes pasarle como parametro (opcional o no, pero ya que es consola generalmente va como param), otra opcion es tener configuracion desde el archivo de config [appSettings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). Cada uno tiene su particularidad o incluso puedes utilizar ambas (si esta en appSetting y si envias por parametro/argumento tiene mas peso). Avisanos o intenta con un prueba de concepto para ayudarte mejor